# SVG Polyline results different from System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline

Tags: svg

I have been replacing a graph made with a System.Windows.Controls.Canvas using its System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline, to a SVG using its Polyline.

When I draw long electrical current trace, everything is on par, using the same 512 data points collection, gives me the exact same trace. But trying to build a XY plot line, gives me different result and I can't figure it out. Is there an option in SVG that I need to use?

Here is an example result in SVG

[image]

Here is the example result in a System.Windows.Controls.Canvas

[image]

Anyone as a tip for me, I definably don't get it.

Thanks!

//////EDIT to add code////////

Ok, here is a few line this is how I generate the polyline( in c#/Blazor Wasm)

```
graphicObjects.Add($@"<polyline fill = ""none"" stroke = ""{color}"" stroke - width = ""1"" points =""{ PointString}"" />");
```

Where PointString is string containing 512 xy couples concatenated with $"{X},{Y}"

Then, it is integrated in the SVG like this

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width=@Width height=@Height>  
        @((MarkupString)HorizontalLine)
        @((MarkupString)VerticalLine)
        @((MarkupString)HorizontalGridLine)
        @((MarkupString)VerticalGridLine)
        @if(@GraphicObjects != null)
        {
            @foreach(var child in @GraphicObjects)
            {
                @((MarkupString)child)
            }
        }
```

Where all the line previous of the GraphicObjects loop are the grid lines we see.

Comment: shape-rendering="crispEdges" perhaps?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: We probably need to see some code then, otherwise we're guessing.